# How to check if checkbox is checked for each row

Tags: laravel-5, model-view-controller, checkbox, eloquent

If one row is checked `if($isset->has('test'))` returns all rows.
I only want to save the marked rows.

**My view file:**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($match->homeTeam->players as $player)
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">{{$player->id}}</th>
         <td class = "col-md-6" name = "player[]" value = "{{$player->id}}">{{$player->name}} {{$player->surname}}</td>
         <td align="center" class= "col-md-2"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="test" value="{{$player->id}}"></td>
         <td class = "col-md-2"><input name="minutes[]"  class="form-control"></td>
         <td class = "col-md-2"><input name="goals[]" class="form-control"></td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function storeMatchFacts(Match $match, Request $request, Match_fact $match_fact, Player $player)
    {
        $home_team_players=$match->homeTeam->players;

          if($isset->has('test')) {
             foreach ( $home_team_players as $k => $p  ) {
                    $data[] = [
                        'match_id' => $match->id,
                        'player_id' => $player->id,
                        'minutes' => $request['minutes'][$k],
                        'goals' => $request['goals'][$k]
                    ];
                }
                dd($data);

        } else {
            dd('error');
}
```

Comment: What is `$isset` variable? How do you get it? Maybe it would be better to write this way: ```if (isset($request->test)) {}```?

Comment: i tryied like you said. But it doesn' work as i want.

Comment: How about changing `name="test"` to `name="test[]"`?